# How to represent List<String> in a feature file in a Cucumber feature file datatable

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am unable to represent `List<String>` in the cucumber datatable in my feature file.

I'm updating a step in a feature file where in that step I simply convert the Cucumber `DataTable` to `List<ObjectB>` using `.asList(ObjectB.class)` provided by the cucumber `DataTable` class. For each row of the DataTable, every field is correctly mapped but the new one being added (`list`) is is just getting mapped as `null` and I cannot figure out how to properly represent this in the datatable in the feature file to stop it getting mapped as `null`.

From the fields below in the feature file table, the `key` and `time` fields get mapped properly but the `list` field always gets mapped as null when I expect it to be converted to a Java `List<Sring>`:

```
Given I create a list of objects:
|  key   |        time          |        list            |
| <key1> | 2022-04-28T00:00:00Z | ["string1", "string2"] |
| <key2> | 2022-05-28T00:00:00Z | ["string3", "string4"] |
```

Step definition:

```
Given("I create a list of objects:", (DataTable dataTable) -> {
    List<ObjectB> objectsList = dataTable.asList(ObjectB.class);
});
```

Class definition for ObjectB:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class ObjectB extends ObjectA {
  private final Instant time;
}
```

Class definition for ObjectA:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class ObjectA {
  private final UUID key;
  private final List<String> list;
}
```

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do that. You could use a doc string and parse that as either json or ndjson.